# Как показать изображение оффлайн в FirebaseDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Вот мой код! Приложение запоминает имя и статус чтобы показать их оффлайн но как мне сохранить изображение чтобы показать их оффлайн. Заранее Спасибо

```
package com.tekemuradov.aman.ulgmada;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private CircleImageView settingsDisplayProfileImage;
    private TextView settingsDisplayName;
    private TextView settingsDisplayStatus;
    private Button settingsChangeProfileImageButton;
    private Button settingsChangeStatusButton;

    private final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference getUserDataReference;
    private StorageReference storeProfileImagestorageRef;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);
        storeProfileImagestorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile_Images");


        settingsDisplayProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_image);
        settingsDisplayName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.settings_username);
        settingsDisplayStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);
        settingsChangeProfileImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_change_profile_image_button);
        settingsChangeStatusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_change_profile_status_button);


        getUserDataReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("user_status").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("user_image").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                settingsDisplayName.setText(name);
                settingsDisplayStatus.setText(status);


                if (!image.equals("default_profile")){
                    Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        settingsChangeProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });
        settingsChangeStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent statusIntent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StatusActivity.class);
                startActivity(statusIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);

        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                StorageReference filePath = storeProfileImagestorageRef.child(user_id + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Surat calysylyar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            getUserDataReference.child("user_image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Surat calysyldy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Yalnyshlyk yuze cykdy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понимаю Picasso автоматом загрузит с кэша картинку если не сможет подключится к интернету. Ни чего делать не надо - попробуйте убрать вашу проверку:

```
if (!image.equals("default_profile")){
                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);
            }
```

Что бы осталось только:

```
Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayProfileImage);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое